Find the slope at a given time value of this equation of a heart
The following equation draws the curve of a heart:
$x(t)=12sin(t)-4sin(3t)$
$y(t)=13cos(t)-5cos(2t)-2cos(3t)-cos(4t)$
Image
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benutzer:Georg-Johann
I would like to find the slope of this curve given a specific value of t.
How can I do this?
I do have a little experience with calculus and differential equations but my memory of this subject isn't the greatest. I have tried taking the first derivative but i am confused how to handle the t variable. The solution does not need to be continuous as I am using this in a programming application. Any advice or guidance that would put me in the right direction would be much appreciated. thanks.

Short answer: you can use the chain rule and treat it as a related rates problem.
Longer answer:
$x(t)=12\sin{t}-4\sin{3t}$ so $\frac{dx}{dt}=12\cos{t}-12\cos{3t}$
$y(t)=13\cos{t}-5\cos{2t}-2\cos{3t}-\cos{4t}$ so $\frac{dy}{dt}=-13\sin{t}+10\sin{2t}+6\sin{3t}+4\sin{4t}$
By the chain rule: $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\div\frac{dx}{dt}$
So the gradient is given by $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-13\sin{t}+10\sin{2t}+6\sin{3t}+4\sin{4t}}{12\cos{t}-12\cos{3t}}$
This can be simplified a bit, but not much to:
$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{28\cos{t}+12\cos{2t}+8\cos{3t}-7}{48(\sin{t}\cos{t})}$
